# Header h2, div, and subtitle color not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, colors, safari, background-color

So I'm having a bit of a problem here on my website with the darker sections. Keep in mind this is only happening in Safari.

When I scroll down, the "review", "Some fun facts", and "contact" all go really dark. I tried doing some -webkit- business, but nothing seemed to work. My website is [www.justinbonfini.com](http://www.justinbonfini.com). Again, you'll have to view it in Safari to see what happens.

Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-header text-center wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
     <h2>Reviews</h2>

     <div class="devider"></div>
     <p class="subtitle">What people say about me</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-header {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
.page-header h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
p.subtitle {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: We really would like to see what you have tried so far. Edit your question to show us what you've tried, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though the `cover` div in those sections is above the `h2` container div. Using `z-index` you can position elements to the front.

Try adding something like this to your existing CSS:

```
.page-header {
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! That fixed all my problems! Thank you so much!:)

Comment: @J.Bon - no problem happy to help! The `position:relative` value is the key edition to the CSS but thought I would advise using the `z-index` as well. This then ensures elements are ordered in whatever order you require :)

Comment: @thood87 That's all really good to know! I Tired just using the z-index, but I needed the position: relative  with it. That's such a neat trick.

Comment: @J.Bon - **Quick Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements